# How to append Selenium generated tweets to a dict?

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

My goal is to create a function that will take in a hashtag, generate all tweets from that and append those tweets to a dictionary. Preferably with automatically generated ID numbers (like from the for loop?) and the value being the tweet content.

Its outputting an empty dictionary so i'm not sure where i'm going wrong.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

tweet_dict = {}
def find_hashtags(hashtags):
    browser = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/Vaish/Downloads/chromedriver')
    browser.get('https://twitter.com/hashtag/' + hashtags + '?src=hash')
    browser.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, 100000)')
    time.sleep(1.5)
    tweets = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('content')
    for tweeter in range(len(tweets)):
        print(tweets[tweeter].text)
        tweet_dict['tweeter_%s' % tweeter] = tweets[tweeter].text

find_hashtags('coronavirus')

OUTPUT : {}
```

Comment: _so i'm not sure where i'm going wrong._ Stack Overflow is not a debugging service. Do you have a specific issue?

Comment: Why are the tweets accessed not being appended to the dictionary and printing an empty dict ? I was clear in what the issue is, if your going after semantics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can recommend you to use [Twitter APIs](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets) for this problem instead of Selenium.

First of all, you won't be able to easily collect text via twitter UI. Secondly, it is much faster to collect data via API than using Selenium.

Lastly, in the example above, your locator is incorrect. Instead of searching for `content`, you should be searching for location of each tweet, something like

```
tweets = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[./div[./div[./div[@lang | @article][./span]]]]")
```

I hope this helps. Good luck!